# Gradient full scale background CSS

Tags: css, background, height, width

## Full page CSS3 Gradient Backgrounds:

Alright so I am trying to make my background be a gradient that is always 100% width and height, and it works, except for the fact that nothing will show up on top of it. Here is the code I currently have.

### CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#bodyBg{
    background:rgb(79,143,249) no-repeat center center fixed; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(164,197,252,1) 1%, rgba(79,143,249,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(1%,rgba(164,197,252,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(79,143,249,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(164,197,252,1) 1%,rgba(79,143,249,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(164,197,252,1) 1%,rgba(79,143,249,1) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(164,197,252,1) 1%,rgba(79,143,249,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(164,197,252,1) 1%,rgba(79,143,249,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a4c5fc', endColorstr='#4f8ff9',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:0;
}
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
#bodyBg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
}
#body-404 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width:880px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "URW Palladio L", Arial, Helvetica, "Palatino Linotype";
    z-index:99;
}
</style>
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="body-404">
    <img src="img/logo.png" width="100%">
    <h1><span>Sorry the page you were looking for was not found</span></h1>
    <p>If you believe you got to this page in error, please contact us via <a href="contactus.php">this page</a>.</p><br />
    <font size="120%"><a href="index.php">Return to Homepage</font>
</div>
<div id="bodyBg"></div>
```

### DEMO:

http://mysteriousorigin.com/missing.html

Comment: the gradient [doesn't seem to work](http://jsfiddle.net/2yVRA/). could you provide a working demo?

Comment: I added a link to a demo.

Answer (score 5):

It's generally considered poor practice to have empty elements like your `#bodyBg`.  Just put the background gradient on the html (or body) element and get rid of the useless div:

http://jsfiddle.net/2yVRA/1/

```
html {
    background:rgb(79,143,249) no-repeat center center fixed; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(164,197,252,1) 1%, rgba(79,143,249,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(1%,rgba(164,197,252,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(79,143,249,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(164,197,252,1) 1%,rgba(79,143,249,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(164,197,252,1) 1%,rgba(79,143,249,1) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(164,197,252,1) 1%,rgba(79,143,249,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(164,197,252,1) 1%,rgba(79,143,249,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a4c5fc', endColorstr='#4f8ff9',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
    min-height: 100%;
}
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */

body-404 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width:880px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "URW Palladio L", Arial, Helvetica, "Palatino Linotype";
    z-index:99;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for `-ms-linear-gradient` http://www.impressivewebs.com/dropping-ms-vendor-prefixes-ie10/ IE10 supports the new unprefixed gradient syntax and IE9 doesn't support gradients at all. The current FF and Opera versions support the new unprefixed syntax as well (however, Opera Mobile and Firefox for Android don't) - see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Answer (score 0):

Use the `background-image` CSS property instead of using the image tag. I've made a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqCW6/1/) to show what I mean. I know it's not exactly what you're going for but you should be able to change it for your use pretty quickly. If not, let me know.

Comment: I was trying to make the gradient background as the page's background.

Comment: I think you got confused since I made the mistake of forgetting that last line in the html, it's there now though